# Problems installing and importing basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have a problem when I import basemap library.
I have installed previously these libraries using anaconda prompt:
- Shapely (which includes GEOS library)
- utm
- proj4
- basemap

When I import basemap I get this error:

```
epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\jwdelgado\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\x07naconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\mpl_toolkits\x08asemap\\epsg'
```

It looks that I am missing epsg file, but i do not know how to install it (I asume that when I install basemap with anaconda it would install everything I need)

Also the directory that shows the error does not exist, the actual directory of basemap library is this:
C:\Users\jwdelgado\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap
I do not understand why the name of te directory changes.

How can I solve this? do I have to install the library in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a backslash in `pyproj_datadir` before `basemap` is missing. It is showing as `\x08asemap` instead of `\basemap`. x08 is the character for backspace. Make sure you have a double backslash, `\\`, there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I already fixed that, but it seems like when I install basemap library with anaconda some files are missing, because the file called epsg does not exist.